# Using multiple DirectoryInfo calls with GoDaddy causes an error?

Tags: c#, filesystems, web-hosting

I'm wondering if anyone has come across this issue or knows of a better way to do this with GoDaddy as the web host?

First off I'll say this code works just fine when I run it locally. It's only when I put it out on a GoDaddy site that is causes an error. The idea behind the code is that I want to look at a "Galleries" folder and inside of that main folder I have folders like "Completed" and "Current". This is where the end user will put different folders underneath those. I then get all of those subfolders into a List which I use to create a  as hyperlinks. Those hyperlinks will get all the files in that folder and display them in an image gallery.

Again, it works just fine locally but when I put it on GoDaddy I get an error like `"Could not find a part of the path 'G:\PleskVhosts\websitename\httpdocs\aaw\Galleries\Current".`

Doing some troubleshooting, if I just do the first directory it works fine on GoDaddy. It's not until I add a second or more that I get the above error. I'm stumped as to why I would get this since they are all in their own variables and Lists.

Here is a sample of the code. If I only use the first DirectoryInfo then all is good. It's not until I add the second one that the issue arises.

```
    DirectoryInfo dirComplete = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Galleries/Completed/"));
    DirectoryInfo[] completedFolderList = dirComplete.GetDirectories();
    var completedFolders = new List<Gallery>();
    foreach (var folder in completedFolderList)
    {
        var gallery = new Gallery();
        gallery.GalleryName = folder.Name;
        completedFolders.Add(gallery);
    }

    DirectoryInfo dirCurrent = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Galleries/Current/"));
    DirectoryInfo[] currentFolderList = dirCurrent.GetDirectories();
    var currentFolders = new List<Gallery>();
    foreach (var folder in currentFolderList)
    {
        var gallery = new Gallery();
        gallery.GalleryName = folder.Name;
        currentFolders.Add(gallery);
    }

var vm = new GalleriesViewModel();
vm.CompletedGalleries = completedFolders;
vm.CurrentGalleries = currentFolders;
```

Comment: If you FTP to your site can you verify that the folders exist?

Comment: Yes, but I'll double check it tonight though just to make sure.

Comment: Well, you were correct, the folder wasn't on the server. Even though I had it in my project, when I published the site the folder was never created. I'm assuming that's because it was empty. I had to manually create the empty folder and it all worked. Thanks!